# Loading data from Google Spreadsheet has broken isotope jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-sheets, jquery-isotope, masonry

A while ago I used isotope to make this grid of people. Each had a rollover effect as you can see.

http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/FinTech/index.html

I now want to make the same thing again but feeding the data in from a Google Spreadsheet, which I have succesfully achieved...

http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/fintech-40-2015/index.html

...however, now none of the jQuery works, but I'm not seeing any error messages. The essential code needed appears to be the same.

Have I made an error in the order of which I call the pieces of code? I can't see any problems with it. Is there other limitations of feeding code from google which I've missed?

Any ideas greatly appreciated

..another thing to add which seemed strange is the #content div which holds all the isotope items was being given a height of 0. I've had to add important! css to make the boxes show at all. Strange

Comment: First thing you need to do is update your jQuery from v 1.6.1 and isotope from v 1.4. Isotope is at v2.2 now but if you still want to use v1, it is at 1.5.2. Your jQuery is very old. Once you do that, it will be easier to help you with your issue.

Comment: Thanks thats true, although the working version is using exactly the same versions and seems to be fine

Comment: Yes, and you are not loading json data from google spreadsheet in that one, it seems.

Comment: Correct. Thats the difference. I've tried adding the updated jquery and isotope and I've broken it completely. Any idea which 2 should be compatible without me having to change my jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/n4me9jq8/).
This is using jQuery 1.11 and isotope v2. Since this version of isotope does not use the v1.5 CSS transitions they were removed from your css and the animationOptions were removed. Since you are loading json data, you need to use isotopes appended method.  BTW, I noted that your filters do not work since they are case sensitive. So filtering "london" does nothing but "London" will filter the items. I changed a few to make them work.

See the relevant code below.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var $container = $('#content');
     var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.box',
         filter: '*'              
    });

    $('.filter li a').on( 'click', function() {
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({
            filter: selector
        });
        return false;
    });  


  $(function listBooks() {
       $.getJSON("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1ZHXE5lqr3WspVtnOpWaBUCBFxpxK_DFXoNMcVBAsiZI/od6/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=?",

    function (data) {

        $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, entry) {

            var boxNo = i + 1;

            var item = '<div class="box ' + entry.gsx$sector.$t + ' ' + entry.gsx$location.$t + ' ' + 'box' + boxNo + '">';

            item += '<div class="box-all"><h2 class="box-title">' + entry.gsx$name.$t + ' ' + entry.gsx$surname.$t + '</h2><div class="box-text">' + entry.gsx$title.$t + '</div></div>';

            item += '</div>';
var $items = $('<a>' + item + '</a>');
$container.append($items).isotope( 'appended', $items );
$container.isotope('layout');            
        });

    });

 });
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I updated mine but for some reason the page is reloading on click. Maybe I need to sort the 'return false' part. Also the bottom bit of jQuery I've added isn't doing much. Maybe I haven't linked the right one...
http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/fintech-40-2015/index.html

Comment: I altered your filter links a bit. Try adding the class "filter" to the ul. `<div class="nav first">
        <ul class="filter">`

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle with your hover code in the correct place, inside function listBooks, so it works now

Comment: Thanks so much. Can I ask why the hover code needs to be inside that function? I thought anywhere within the 'document.ready' function would trigger that animation when hovered.